# Angular is not passing execution to Web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using a SQLite database. I'm trying to insert record into the `Departments` table.

This is the code in my Web API controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveDept(CreateDepartmentDto dept)
{
    var deptEntity = _mapper.Map<Department>(dept);
    return Ok(await _departmentRepository.SaveDepartment(deptEntity));
}
```

Here is my Angular component code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-insert-dept',
  templateUrl: './insert-dept.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./insert-dept.component.css']
})
export class InsertDeptComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = {};

  constructor(private databaseService: DatabaseService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  SaveDepartment() {
    console.log(this.model);
    this.databaseService.InsertDept(this.model);
  }
}
```

And this is the code in my Angular service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatabaseService {
  apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  InsertDept(dept: DeptDtoForInsert) {
    this.http.post<DeptDtoForInsert>(this.apiUrl, dept).pipe(
      map(response => {
      })
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on the "Save" button, the execution is passed from my Angular component through my Angular service. But, I am unable to catch hold of the execution in my Web API project and execution is not hitting in my Web API post method. When verified in the database, I don't see any new record is inserted in the database.

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong, and how to resolve the issue?

Regards,
Ashok Kumar K.

Answer (score 3):

Try add **.subscribe()** to trigger it:

```
InsertDept(dept: DeptDtoForInsert) {
  this.http.post<DeptDtoForInsert>(this.apiUrl, dept).pipe(
    map(response => {
        
    })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use .subscribe() in the component too

```
SaveDepartment() {
  console.log(this.model);
  this.databaseService.InsertDept(this.model).subscribe(
    (result) => {},
    (error) => {}
  )
}
```

and you should return the response from the service

```
InsertDept(dept: DeptDtoForInsert) {
   return this.http.post<DeptDtoForInsert>(this.apiUrl, dept).pipe(
     map(response => {
     })
   );
}
```